# how should i decode the correct json response?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.7 to build an API that provides a JSON response. I am creating the following JSON but it needs some changes. Table contain booking_pics columns in which multiple images stored using , separated. I want fetch in json as object in array. i am display json but only last image is display others is not, need solution.

**Controller:**

```
$get_booking_details= DB::table('table_booking_list')
            ->join('table_booking_details', 'table_booking_list.booking_id', '=', 'table_booking_details.booking_id')
            ->select('table_booking_details.*')
            ->where('table_booking_details.booking_id',$booking_id)
            ->get();

            foreach($get_booking_details as $item)
            {
                foreach(explode(",",$item->booking_pics) as $items)
                {
                   $item->booking_pics=[["image" => $items]];
                }
            }
            return response()->json(['success' => '1','data' =>$get_booking_details]);
```

**json response:**

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "booking_list_id": 1,
            "booking_id": 1,
            "booking_name": "hockey stadium",
            "booking_area": "kolhapur",
            "booking_status": 0,
            "time": "6.00 am to 8.00pm",
            "booking_pics": [
                {
                    "image": "http://192.168.1.132:8000/images/ground_pic/2.jpg"
                }
            ],
            "available_sports": "hockey,cricket",
            "booking_amenities": "parking,toilet,water",
            "booking_rating": 4.5,
            "booking_area_address": "MSEB Ring Road, Datta Colony, Kolhapur, Maharashtra, 416008",
            "longitude": "85.501980",
            "latitude": "23.624420",
            "updated_at": "2019-06-26 16:42:02",
            "created_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Required json:**

```
{
    "success": "1",
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "booking_list_id": 1,
        "booking_id": 1,
        "booking_name": "hockey stadium",
        "booking_area": "kolhapur",
        "booking_status": 0,
        "time": "6.00 am to 8.00pm",
        "booking_pics": [{
                "image": "http://192.168.1.132:8000/images/ground_pic/1.jpg"
            },
            {
                "image": "http://192.168.1.132:8000/images/ground_pic/2.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "available_sports": "hockey,cricket",
        "booking_amenities": "parking,toilet,water",
        "booking_rating": 4.5,
        "booking_area_address": "MSEB Ring Road, Datta Colony, Kolhapur, Maharashtra, 416008",
        "longitude": "85.501980",
        "latitude": "23.624420",
        "updated_at": "2019-06-26 16:42:02",
        "created_at": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }]
}
```

Comment: You can try `$item->booking_pics[]=["image" => $items];`

Comment: @DhananjayKyada no error occur

Comment: @DhananjayKyada error ' Illegal string offset 'image'' plz sir need help

Comment: Please try `$item->images[]=$items`.

Comment: @DhananjayKyada    [] operator not supported for strings this error accur Plz check required json

Comment: May `foreach ($get_booking_details as $item) {
        $booking_images = [];
        foreach (explode(",", $item->booking_pics) as $items) {
            $booking_images['image'][] = $items;
        }
        $item->put('booking_pics', $booking_images);
    }`
will help you

Comment: error occur for put method

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @DhananjayKyada Call to undefined method stdClass::put()

Comment: Please check with `foreach ($get_booking_details as $item) {
    $booking_images = [];
    foreach (explode(",", $item->booking_pics) as $items) {
        $booking_images['image'][] = $items;
    }
    $item->put('booking_pics_images', $booking_images);
}`

Comment: same error occur

Comment: @DhananjayKyada Are you solve it?

Comment: what are you getting with `dd($item->booking_pics)`?

Comment: @DhananjayKyada   "http://192.168.1.132:8000/images/ground_pic/1.jpg,http://192.168.1.132:8000/images/ground_pic/2.jpg"

Comment: check required json format i lost my first image in json

Answer (score 0):

> Do it this way

```
        foreach($get_booking_details as $item)
        {
            foreach(explode(",",$item->booking_pics) as $items)
            {
               $item->booking_pics["image"][] = $items;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

fastest way would be creating a model and casting the data from database as a json

in model

```
protected $casts = [
    'booking_pics' => 'json',
];
```